# WPF optimize loading on the UI thread

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, prism

I am trying to optimize the loading times for my WPF prism application. The loading is basically a loop of using reflection to create instances of UI elements and then adding them to the main window (the shell) in a tab control.

Since we are limited to using a single thread to create all the objects, what would be the optimal way to speed up loading / create a better user experience?

These are the options I have so far:

1. Use lazy loading. Only load the tab when the user first clicks on it. But that would have a 4-5 second delay opening the first time as it gets initialized on demand.
2. Cache all the reflection calls. I actually did that, but it did not speed anything up at all. Most of the time occurs during the rendering of the controls...
3. ?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated for this tricky problem.

Comment: How can loading the content of a tab could possibly take 4-5 seconds ? What does it involve ?

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970683.aspx

Comment: @NicolasRepiquet The UI is composed of tabs. Each tab can have up to 15 sub controls: maps, charts, forms, etc. Each sub control needs to deserialize itself and then the layout has to be calculated and the control rendered. It is not a trivial app, these things can add up.

Comment: How many tabs?   I don't know prism but what I do is load active tab and then start loading the other tabs.  But I am loading expensive data not UI controls so it would be trickier.

Comment: Each sub control needs to deserialize itself? Do you recieve your UI from a web service or something like that?

Comment: @Blam It could be up to 10 tabs, each with 9-10 controls. its like a dashboard.

Comment: @HighCore i should have been more clear. the sub controls deserialize their state and apply their state. The problem I am having is that the entire burden is on the UI thread for everything since all the controls inherit from dispatcher

Comment: I still don't understand... what do you mean by "state"? their properties? post some sample code so we can understand it a little better

Comment: @HighCore "state" from wikipedia is: "In computer science and automata theory, the state of a digital logic circuit or computer program is a technical term for all the stored information, at a given point in time, which is used by the circuit or program." That is what I mean. no more, no less. sample code is not required

Comment: yeah, good theory crap, my point is that if you would have implemented MVVM (which is the right way to do WPF applications) you could inflate your data in whatever thread you wish, and then bind that to the view via databinding.

Comment: @HighCore not true. to participate in databinding, the object must inherit from dependencyObject. dependencyObjects must all be created on the same thread as the window owner. the proper way to do this is to create wrapper objects that encapsulate only data and do not inherit from dependencyObject. this approach is too cumbersome because it will requires 1:1 DTOs for each bindable class.

Comment: too cumbersome?? what kind of application doesn't have a DATA model?? in order to do databinding you do not necessarily need to do DependencyObjects. There is also INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @HighCore thanks for your comments. we have considered INotifyPropertyChanged already. I am looking for creative / elegant solutions. If there are none, I can accept that.

Comment: I had a similar problem with my WPF Prism app.  I added a splash screen to my app and that helped.  It did not speed up loading time, but the app is not in a "Hung" state.  The splash screen shows which modules are loading.  This helps the user experience.  If you want info on a prism splash screen let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer to speeding up the loading is to simply hide the container while the visual tree is being constructed.

This prevents the screen from constantly needing to update itself.

When all the elements have been added to the visual tree, then setting the container visibility to visible renders the tab container once.

We also implemented some simple lazy-rendering to the tab control items.

Net result: loading times from 2 minutes down to about 20 seconds.

Comment: 20 seconds to load an application still sounds like too much to me... we have a large LOB application that goes from Entity Framework thru WCF to WPF and the server side is hosted in a hosting center in CA and the users are in Florida and it takes no more than 7 or 8 seconds to load up the initial screen, which then keeps loading data and processing stuff in the background, without being noticed by the end user.

Answer (score 3):

You're pretty much stuck as you can only load objects on the main thread, so I don't think you'll make it load any faster.

What you can do is distract the user:  I have an animated splash screen that take about 10 seconds to work its way through the animation sequence.  This serves a number of purposes:

1. It shows the user motion - so they have a visual cue that something is going on
2. It distracts them and fills the space taken by the initial load

To ensure smooth animation you need to create a second dispatcher.  Here's how I do it:

```
public class AppEntry : Application
    {
        private static ManualResetEvent _resetSplashCreated;

        internal static Thread SplashThread { get; set; }

        internal static SplashWindow SplashWindow { get; set; }

        private static void ShowSplash()
        {
            SplashWindow = new SplashWindow();
            SplashWindow.Show();
            _resetSplashCreated.Set();
            Dispatcher.Run();
        }

        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            _resetSplashCreated = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            SplashThread = new Thread(ShowSplash);
            SplashThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            SplashThread.IsBackground = true;
            SplashThread.Name = "Splash Screen";
            SplashThread.Start();

            _resetSplashCreated.WaitOne();

            var app = new App();
            app.DispatcherUnhandledException += new DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(app_DispatcherUnhandledException);
            app.InitializeComponent();
            app.Run();

        }

        static void app_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
           // MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

I set the AppEntry class as my Startup Object in the Project Properties/Application tab.
I close my splash screen at the end of my OnStartup method in App:

```
 AppEntry.SplashWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                                                             new Action(() => AppEntry.SplashWindow.Close()));
```

Is this faster?  No
Does the user think it's faster?  Yes

Sometimes, if you can't give them speed, you can give them activity.  It's a nice placebo.

Comment: +1 for splash screen making the user think it is loading faster.

Comment: @Faster Solutions Thank you for the suggestion and sample code. I am using a splash screen, but it is not that responsive since the UI thread is always spinning. This idea of creating the splash window on another thread has merit. I am going to try a few suggestions and i will get back to you. thanks!

Comment: The important thing to remember here is that we're running 2 Dispatchers, so while your app is getting itself ready you can do something "pretty" in the splash window.  In my case I've used blend to take the company icon and do some origami with it.

Comment: how do i award partial credit? I want to give you credit for your response as well.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, You cannot Multithread if your objects are DependencyObjects. [Kent Boogart discusses this](http://kentb.blogspot.com.ar/2009/03/view-models-pocos-versus.html). That's why you must leverage [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://wpftutorial.net/INotifyPropertyChanged.html) and do POCO objects to hold your data. That way you can multithread to obtain the data and then bind these to your UI. Another drawback of using DependencyObjects is that you're tying your application too much to the WPF framework (DependencyObject being a class defined in the System.Windows namespace in a WPF assembly (don't remember if PresentationCore or PresentationFramework)). If refactoring is not an option, you will have to consider a solution like the one LastCoder proposed. Be aware that you will be able to do very little multithreading (if any at all), therefore your application is not going to be very responsive all the time.

Comment: thanks again for your insight. we do indeed have POCO objects that are used to shuffle data around. these objects tend to have a very short lifespan before they are transformed into (DependencyObjects) objects that we use in binding. your suggestion seems to indicate we should keep these server objects around longer. thisn may be a good way to cache the objects or fetch them all concurently. i am going to try some things out and will get back to you.

Comment: Even a POCO that implements INotifyPropertyChanged did not help us. Our poco objects contain controls that need to be deserialized so we had the same thread affinity issues.

Comment: your problem is that you did not separate UI from business logic / data. your views should not be deserialized or otherwise created from data. Your views should be pure XAML defined in design time in the application. Then you can bind this XAML controls to normal CLR properties in normal objects obtained in whatever way from whatever thread

Comment: controls should not be contained by anything other than the Visual layer of the application, completely decoupled from the data layer, and only referencing the data via Bindings.

Comment: This is what makes WPF and MVVM different from Winforms and any other UI frameworks that I know of, the fact that you can (and should) separate UI from application logic an data in a REAL way

Comment: Take a look at the Kent Boogart blog i linked to.. it's like a brief introduction to what an MVVM application looks like... ViewModels contain data, and application logic, and under no circumstances should these contain UI-specific classes such as controls or windows.

Comment: I still would like you to post some sample code, because I still cannot fully understand what you've done, and how UI elements are being created and connected together

Answer (score 1):

I would implement a timer that loads a few controls or tabs every tick (iteration). The timer will run on the same thread as the UI (control messages for it will be queued up on the Windows Message Loop). Once all of the work is done you can kill the timer.

The timer interval and the number of controls to load per tick will boil down to use-testing; try something like 100ms and 2 controls a tick that will give you ~20 controls a second, so if you had 10 tabs with 15 controls each it would take ~8seconds, but the UI shouldn't lock up as bad.

Comment: this is an interesting idea. I will give it a try and let you know if the approach seems effective. i've never done this before, so I won't know until I try.

Comment: We ended up hiding the tab container during loading. This was the most elegant solution because it prevented the UI from constantly rendering itself.